# How to generate synthetic groups with count of zero

Tags: sql, group-by, count

Imagine I have this data:

```
id   |   category
1    |   cat_1
2    |   cat_3
3    |   cat_3
4    |   cat_1
```

Notice there are no `cat_2` values present, but I know that `cat_2` is a possible value, and I want reports to reflect that.

If I write a simple query to `COUNT` items and `GROUP BY` category, I end up with:

```
category   |   count(item)
cat_1      |   2
cat_3      |   2
```

When instead I want:

```
category   |   count(item)
cat_1      |   2
cat_2      |   0
cat_3      |   2
```

Using vanilla ANSI SQL, no particular dialect... what is the most efficient way to get the result I'm after? I can think of a few particularly hacky approaches, but there has got to be a cleaner way.

Comment: Do you have a list of all the `category` values?

Comment: @Nick, yes. It's not defined in a physical table anywhere, but it is known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you should have a dedicated `category` table, which keeps track of all categories which exist and should appear in your query output.  That failing, you can try inlining a subquery which contains all categories which you want to appear:

```
SELECT
    c.category,
    COUNT(t.id) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT 'cat_1' AS category UNION ALL
    SELECT 'cat_2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'cat_3'
) c
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON c.category = t.category
GROUP BY
    c.category;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect.